# How to insert array values into multiple rows of a column in a database table?

Tags: php, arrays, database

i have been trying to write a program to insert the array values in multiple rows of a column in a database table. After lot of trial I couldn't get the proper output I wanted.

My database table looks like this

```
    id   | values  |
    1    |         |
    2    |         |
    4    |         |
    5    |         |
    6    |         |
```

and I have 2nd column values as an array and I want to enter those values in the second column.

The output should look like this:-

```
    id   | values  |
    1    |     2   |
    2    |     3   |
    4    |     7   |
    5    |     9   |
    6    |     10  |
```

So, I have two array values `$id` and `$values`...So, I want to fill `$values` in each row of the column for each respective `$id` values

NOTE : `$id` is already filled in the database

Comment: How do you have the array? Put that array here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have an array with the id values in it.

You may try something like this:

```
foreach($XArray as $key => $value){

$sql = "UPDATE TABLENEAME ".
       "SET value = $value ".
       "WHERE id = $key" ;

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
}
```

I haven't checked the code, its just a sample.

With respect to the updated question:

```
$count=sizeof($value);
for($counter=0;$counter<$count;$counter++){

    $sql = "UPDATE TABLENEAME ".
           "SET value = $value[$counter]".
           "WHERE id = $id[$counter]" ;

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ) or die ("Error in query: $sql");
    }
```

Comment: because i want use $value and insert it into each row of the column name (value). As written above... could you please modify your code accordingly...

Comment: Ya thats the thing confused me little. clause should be given like this??  **$sql= "UPDATE TABLENEAME "."SET value = $value "."WHERE id = $id" ;**

Comment: first could you add `echo $sql;` and check that all the queries are being formed..?

Comment: if the queries are forming correctly try the edited code. Hope it should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
{
     $query = "INSERT INTO table
                  SET values = $value,
                  id = $key
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE values = $value";
}
```

I do not know what sort of database you are using, this example is for MySQL.

And I also don't know how you insert information in the DB ( simple mysql_query, pdo, frameworks, ... ), so you should use the function you need and pass that query string and, if needed, don't forget to properly sanitize the array.

EDIT : I also assume that id is a primary key or unique index

Comment: Insert query does not have a where clause.

Comment: God, thank you Karan Punamiya, I was not paying attention. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value){
   // <INSERT QUERY LINE HERE > ( you have to insert $value insite 'values' )
}
```

Comment: @Peteris ya i did the same... but i think the problem is my database query

Comment: it should be smth like `mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES ('$value')");`

Comment: its printing the first value of the array $value

Comment: has your id (in mysql) have AUTO INCREMENT?  AAND try to `echo $value;` if it prins out only first value - problem is in your array,btw, you really could show us your array!

Comment: the array is fine.. when i echo the value, it prints the proper array values as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array values in a loop and on each iteration of the loop make and execute a query. The sample code will look something like this, change it as according to your variables and need.

```
foreach ($array as $id => $values) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (id ,values) VALUES ($id , $values)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```